# ASP.NET Web Api bearer Token automatic prolongation

Tags: asp.net, .net, authentication, asp.net-web-api, token

I have SPA app and token authentication, but I want to achieve default session/cookie authentication like MVC or Web Forms. In other words, I want my tokens to use like `SessionId`-s. A token should be automatically prolonged after service call, also should expire after 20 mins of last call.
Is there a way to configure default implementation of Web API to achieve this functional?